# Switching modal forms in Delphi

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog

I have a modal form (A) that shows another modal form (B). B displays a dataset and allows the user to interact with it. My problem is that one action requires that A becomes again the focused form so the user can input certain values without closing B. I have tried A.BringToFront and A.SetFocus and it indeed is shown at front, but the input focus remains in B and any click or the like in A results in the windows "ding" when you click where you should not. The code is some how like

A.ShowModal;
.
.
. inside an event of A:
B.ShowModal();
.
.
. inside an event of B:

someobject.someMethodThatRequiresAFocused;

My guess is that some obscure and strange API call could make A modal again ¿Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: The only obscure thing is in your code :-) No, just kidding. But that's just how modal works, and why it is called "modal". What you want is a non-modal window.

Comment: Why not put everything on one form? You can separate the section using a pagecontrol. You can even flip between the pages programmatically.

Answer (score 5):

When a modal form is shown, all currently visible forms **including other modal forms** are disabled.  As such, it is not possible to switch between multiple modal forms.  You need to re-think your UI design so that `B` does not go back to `A` for new input.  At the very least, you could have `B` open a new modal form `C` that prompts the user for just the needed values and gives them to `B`, and then either `B` or `C` can update `A` with the new values afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

There's no API that toggles modality between windows. In any case the API you're looking for your case is `EnableWindow`. That's how modality works, windows other than the one that the user should be working with are disabled so that he/she cannot interact with them. This is also the reason for the 'ding' sound, to provide feedback to the user.

So while letting the user work with a window that's been disabled in favor of another modal window is technically easy, handling states may not be straight forward. I present a bare minimum example below for what it would seem to take.

'FormB' first. Lets suppose you pass a reference of 'FormA' in the 'Owner' parameter while 'FormA' is constructing 'FormB'. The below is what the code that should make 'FormA' modal again could look like:

```
procedure TFormB.BtnMakeFormAModalAgainClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Enabled := False;                  // so that 'A' will behave like it's modal
  EnableWindow(TFormA(Owner).Handle, True);  // so that 'A' could be interacted
  TFormA(Owner).SetFocus;
end;
```

When this code runs, what happens is 'FormA' is enabled and brought to front, and 'FormB' is disabled - will produce a 'ding' when clicked on.

But we're not done yet. Because we have modified the meaning of modality - now we don't want 'FormA' to be closed when the user is done with it. Below is how could the code in 'FormA's unit could look like:

```
type
  TFormA = class(TForm)
    BtnShowModalB: TButton;
    BtnOk: TButton;
    procedure BtnShowModalBClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnOkClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FModalB: TForm;
  end;

implementation

uses
  unitOfFormB;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormA.BtnShowModalBClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FModalB := TFormB.Create(Self);  // so that FormB can find FormA from the Owner
  FModalB.ShowModal;
  FModalB.Free;
  FModalB := nil; // Need this if we're going to decide if FormB is showing 
                  // by testing against this reference
end;

procedure TFormA.BtnOkClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FModalB) then begin // is FormB the actual modal form?
    EnableWindow(Handle, False);  // disable this form so it would 'ding'
    FModalB.Enabled := True;      // enable FormB, so user can interact with it
    FModalB.SetFocus;
    ModalResult := mrNone;        // don't close, FormB is the first one to be closed
  end else
    ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

I'm nearly positive that this example is not complete, but here's the API that you're looking for.